# New itunes connect crash logs

Tags: app-store-connect

How can i find crash logs in the new itunes connect? The documentation on apple, refers to the old itunes connect, but cannot find it nowhere in the new version

Comment: Are you only seeing Promo Codes, Status History, and Version Summary as well?

Comment: Hi Peter – the accepted answer is currently out of date and misleading. Another directing users to the [xcode organiser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39398485/2547229) is the correct answer. Would you consider updating?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Actually they have integrated it to your XCode organizer. if you open organizer in XCode, and select your app, in the top, you will find archive and crashes tab.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it appears you can only get 2 weeks of crashes this way.

Comment: For those that don't know what Organizer is: Open Window -> Organizer. The top of the new window that appears has two tabs, Archives and Crashes.

Comment: Only naive people assume that Apple would offer those logs at the same point where they offer *everything* else about your app, i.e. in iTunes Connect.

Comment: Ironically, after following those steps and clicking 'Open in Project' to view my crash log/info, Xcode promptly crashed! haha

Comment: @RAM237 oh yes, such an inconvenience to have the crash logs available right in Xcode instead of having to log in on App Store Connect...

Comment: @hendrik, what are you talking about? they'd have always been in itunes connect.