# "App is crashing on startup" in Apple App store, but it works fine in Debug/Adhock?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a blank app, which is having none code.
I've generated corresponding provisioning profiles for it and attached them to it.
I've set the compiler options - generate universal binary.

I have Mac OS X 10.11.1 ( El Capitan ), XCode 7.1, iOS SDK 9.1, Delphi 10 Seattle.
I am testing on iPad 3 / iOS 9.1 and iPhone 4 / iOS 7.1.2

When I try in debug and adhock  - the app runs like charm, anyway my builds is rejected in Apple Application Store by the reason :

*"2.1 Details*

*We were unable to review your app, as it crashed on launch.*

*Next Steps*

*Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing."*

- What could be the possible reason of causing this issue ?

Comment: If someone Delphi user which have been actually uploaded recently to app store an app for iOS 9, which were approved - please share your configuration.

Comment: Did they send you a crash report?

Comment: We have a similar problem. OSX 10.10.4 Yosemite. Xcode 7.0.1. iOS SDK 9.0. Delphi 10 Seattle. Testing on iPhone 4S with iOS 9.0.2. Running in debug works, but running in release configuration causes app to crash on startup. Funny thing is that the app actually passed App Store Review like that. We now have an app on the App Store that crashes on startup. The other difference to the OP's situation is that a new blank multi-device application works fine in release configuration for us. We have tried recreating the project file, but no difference.

Comment: I had a similar problem and it was related to certificated, I have to install the AppleWWDRCA certificate.
http://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

Comment: installed it. no change..

Comment: Did Apple send you a crash report when they rejected the app?

Comment: By any chance is any of your code written in swift and are you checking for iPads with a macro like this? UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()  If so then you need to change that macro as it is known to cause a crash immediately when running with release builds (not debug)

Comment: Hi @BinaryGuy, I've checked the current Delphi source files, but I have found none reference to this macro. Any idea where I should look for it ?

Comment: @Bruno Coelho nope. I don't see any link to a  crash report in the notifying mail.

Comment: @YordanYanakiev The email should have a link to itunes connect and there you should have an attachment.

Comment: @Bruno Coelho  I am unable to find anything like this in the itunesconnect

Comment: @YordanYanakiev check this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888677/new-itunes-connect-crash-logs

Comment: Nope. I don't have such an option. I have Resolution Center link, no crash report.

Comment: The automated system for export which I implemented turns out that add an device ID even on the blank apps. Which leads to this "Blank app" confusion. Anyway thanks again @BinaryGuy - You've solve it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the hint @BinaryGuy have made is solution of the problem.
Seems like UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM is kept and linked into the compiled IPA if the developer use some of the classes containing a link toward it.

The classes which causing the issues is primarely related to the previously accessible hardware ID's on the Apple products, now these classes seems like is deprecated and causing the Application Store rejection without obvious reason.

Please if You are using some of the follow Delphi units :

**FMX.Helpers.iOS.pas** (**TUIDevice / UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad** references),

**iOSapi.UIKit.pas** (**UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone** references),

**FMX.Platform.iOS.pas** (**UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad** references),

double check if they could be avoided.

Comment: Please if this was helpful info for You - upvote as well the comment made by @BinaryGuy in the Question thread. Thank You. :)